# orgtbl-toggle-comment freeze in one line table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, orgtbl

For example, write **only one line** in `foo.org`.

```
| a |
```

So if execute `M-x orgtbl-toggle-comment`, it will freeze.
(can stop with C-g)

Is there a way to solve this?

environment:

> org-version is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
> Its value is "9.3"

Comment: If you `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, then when you press that `C-g`, you would get a backtrace, which would allow you to debug the problem (I assume that's how @matteol found the problem to come up with the fixed version in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in `orgtbl-toggle-comment` that gets stuck on the line

```lisp
(while (looking-at re) (beginning-of-line 0))
```

if the table is on the first line of the buffer. You can use the following patched definition of the function. I'll submit a bug report to org.

```lisp
(defun orgtbl-toggle-comment ()
  "Comment or uncomment the orgtbl at point."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((case-fold-search t)
     (re1 (concat "^" (regexp-quote comment-start) orgtbl-line-start-regexp))
     (re2 (concat "^" orgtbl-line-start-regexp))
     (commented (save-excursion (beginning-of-line 1)
                    (cond ((looking-at re1) t)
                      ((looking-at re2) nil)
                      (t (user-error "Not at an org table")))))
     (re (if commented re1 re2))
     beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line 1)
      (while (and (looking-at re) (not (eql (point) (point-min))))
        (beginning-of-line 0))
      (unless (looking-at re) (beginning-of-line 2))
      (setq beg (point))
      (while (looking-at re) (beginning-of-line 2))
      (setq end (point)))
    (comment-region beg end (if commented '(4) nil))))
```

Comment: I guess it does not make much difference, but why `eql` and not `=`?

Comment: @NickD I always forget `=` exists

Comment: @megeton: if this answered your question, please [accept the answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). That's how the site is supposed to work: accepting an answer makes it clear to whoever has the same question in the future that there is at least one answer that resolved the problem.